# How can I change the Google search locale with OS X Lion Safari 5

Tags: safari

Whenever I perform a search in Safari it takes me to google.com. I am in the UK, so results for eShops etc the results are not relevant - I need google.co.uk.

How do I change the search engine? I don't want to use the Glims plugin because it interferes with the toolbar in a subtle way that I don't like (I can explain if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a few articles I found, it sounds like this isn't directly supported in Safari.

However, there is [a Safari extension](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/safari-uk-search/) that will redirect `google.com` to `google.co.uk` and should take care of your problem. (This is a simple extension, using the built-in mechanism, and not a plugin.)

Comment: Thanks, nice minimal extension - seems like this is the way to go for now!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create/use a Google ID, and log into Google to choose a base site, and from that point on any searches that head over to .com should automatically redirect to .co.uk - so the answer is by configuring Google, not by configuring Safari.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding a location under google.co.uk/preferences, it probably helps with Google shopping results but not if you end up on Amazon.com.

Answer (score 0):

Neither solutions are any good for me.

I need to be able to search a choice of international googles - english uk, spanish spain, german etc.

What I do is change the google suffix to select engine after the initial search e.g. from [google.es](http://www.google.es/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=fuerteventura&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=dZjYT6elAoTDhAfj0I3nAw) to [google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=fuerteventura&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=dZjYT6elAoTDhAfj0I3nAw). But it's fiddly - I'd much prefer a system like IE's where you can add in any search engine you like.

I'm surprised Apple haven't come up with something or is it the usual case of 'We know what's best for you'?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Safari Omnibar](http://hackemist.com/SafariOmnibar/) which allows configuration of the search engine you want to use (and also integrates the address and the search box into one).

From the web site:

- Unified location bar with search bar
- Search directly using location bar
- Quickly switch engines using search engine keywords
- Define new search engines